# Margin-top doesn't work right

Tags: html, css

I want to make the top margin of a h2 class bigger then it is now. I tried applying margin-top and padding, but they both didn't work. When i use margin-top on the h2portfolio class, the margin-top of section 1 (so a totally different section) changes.

U can see this on interlaser.webovo.nl. I need to change the margin of the orange 'Portfolio' h2, so class "h2portfolio".

The html i used to build that section:

```
<h2 class="h2portfolio">Portfolio</h2>
<div id="portfolio1">
<h2 class="h2portfolio1">Feesten</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio1"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="portfolio2">
<h2 class="h2portfolio2">Kunst</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio2"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="portfolio3">
<h2 class="h2portfolio3">Overige</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio3"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

the css i used:

```
.h2portfolio {
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
color: #F16C20;
}

#portfolio1 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
#portfolio2 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
#portfolio3 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

.portfolio1 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
.portfolio2 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
.portfolio3 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
```

Comment: Post the related CSS as well

Comment: display:inline-block to the element to margin

Comment: @Roy i need the portfolio above the pictures, and centered. When i use display: inline-block the h2 slides to the right and a bit down. Do i need to wrap the h2 in a div?

Comment: you want to give **margin-top** to **portfolio** title . right?

Comment: @BhavinShah right

Answer (score 1):

I have made the updates in the answer.

1 : make a separate div for **lazershow** contents
2 : make a separate div for **portfolio** title & its contents and then give **margin**(as per your need) to the **portfolio** div which satisfy your requirements.

```css
.lazershow{
  background:white;
  height:200px;
}

.portfolio_div{
  border:thin black solid;
}
.h2portfolio {
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
color: #F16C20;
margin-top:10%; /*Give margin as per your need*/
}

#portfolio1 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
#portfolio2 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
#portfolio3 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

.portfolio1 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
.portfolio2 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
.portfolio3 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lazershow">
LazerShow Div
</div>
<div class="portfolio_div">
  <h2 class="h2portfolio">Portfolio</h2>
<div id="portfolio1">
<h2 class="h2portfolio1">Feesten</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio1"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="portfolio2">
<h2 class="h2portfolio2">Kunst</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio2"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="portfolio3">
<h2 class="h2portfolio3">Overige</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio3"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have given `margin-top` to `h2portfolio` class.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/825oqum7/2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something weird happens when i do that. When i give margin-top: 100px to the h2portfolio, the margin between the header picture and the 'Lasershow' title becomes 100px. So when i give a margin-top to h2portfolio, it applies to the h2lasershow. The difference between 'Portfolio' and the section above stays the same. Why does this happen?

Comment: it is because **portfolio** title is with **Lasershow** div. can't you put it in separate div and give margin as per your need to your **portfolio** div

Comment: the portfolio title is in section-portfolio.php and the lasershow is in section-lasershow.php so it's not in the same div...

Comment: okay then give extra `margin-top` into `section-portfolio.php` by adding new `div` . and check if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `margin-top: 100px;` and `padding-bottom:15px;` style in `.h2portfolio` class as you need.

```css
.h2portfolio {
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
color: #F16C20;
margin-top: 100px;
padding-bottom:15px;
}

#portfolio1 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
#portfolio2 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
#portfolio3 {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}

.portfolio1 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
.portfolio2 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
.portfolio3 {
margin-top: 7.5%;
margin-right: 7.5%;
margin-left: 7.5%;
margin-bottom: 7.5%;
width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="h2portfolio">Portfolio</h2>
<div id="portfolio1">
<h2 class="h2portfolio1">Feesten</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio1"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="portfolio2">
<h2 class="h2portfolio2">Kunst</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio2"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div id="portfolio3">
<h2 class="h2portfolio3">Overige</h2>
<a href="http://interlaser.webovo.nl"><img class="portfolio3"src="http://interlaser.webovo.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/cropped-cropped-maxresdefault-300x204.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Something weird happens when i do that. When i give margin-top: 100px to the h2portfolio, the margin between the header picture and the 'Lasershow' title becomes 100px. So when i give a margin-top to h2portfolio, it applies to the h2lasershow. The difference between 'Portfolio' and the section above stays the same. Why does this happen?

Comment: This is happened When you have use same class for all.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your class "`.h2portfolio`":

```
.h2portfolio {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F16C20;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom:15px;
  //line new added
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```